# Different ST_Distance calculation with degrees and metres in PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, geometry, postgis, distance, geography

I have noticed that sometimes the results from ST_Distance for geometry types do not correspond correctly to those for geography types.
For example:

```
SELECT ST_Distance('SRID=4326;MULTIPOLYGON(((13.1654379639367 48.0163296656575,
13.1654405823308 48.0163326202901,13.1654809135407 48.0163781648167,
13.1655095556032 48.0164104945946,13.1656825124596 48.0166031792699,
13.1658285825017 48.0167559797112,13.1658385904811 48.0167667179682,
13.1660097634653 48.0169315381006,13.1661737540995 48.0170911295992,
13.166336100685 48.0172329598378,13.1677079127931 48.0150783894135,
13.1677278111466 48.0150450062427,13.1670716137939 48.0148839705059,
13.1667911667995 48.0148062288149,13.1665512255895 48.0147411405409,
13.1665145733757 48.0147311909654,13.1654379639367 48.0163296656575)))'::geometry, 
'SRID=4326;POINT(16.096346 47.2786129)'::geometry);
```

returns 3.0197908442784636 as a result in degrees.

But, when computing the distance of the same shapes in metres:

```
 SELECT ST_Distance(gg1,gg2) from (select 'SRID=4326;MULTIPOLYGON(((13.1654379639367 48.0163296656575,
 13.1654405823308 48.0163326202901,13.1654809135407 48.0163781648167,13.1655095556032 48.0164104945946,
 13.1656825124596 48.0166031792699,13.1658285825017 48.0167559797112,13.1658385904811 48.0167667179682,
 13.1660097634653 48.0169315381006,13.1661737540995 48.0170911295992,13.166336100685 48.0172329598378,
 13.1677079127931 48.0150783894135,13.1677278111466 48.0150450062427,13.1670716137939 48.0148839705059,
 13.1667911667995 48.0148062288149,13.1665512255895 48.0147411405409,13.1665145733757 48.0147311909654,
 13.1654379639367 48.0163296656575)))'::geography as gg1, 
'SRID=4326;POINT(16.096346 47.2786129)'::geography as gg2) as foo;
```

it returns 0 metres. This can't be right. By looking the shapes in wkt playground the distance is indeed much more than 0 metres.

Any idea of what I could be doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: In this specific case, it doesn't like the multipolygon (but the function do usually work with multipolygon geographies). You can try the usual trick to fix "weird but valid" geometries/geographies, by using `st_buffer(gg1,0)`  (which, in this example, will turn the geog to a simple polygon)

Comment: Great, it works! Thank you!